# .Net Framework stub generation utility not generating expected classes

Tags: .net, web, service, stub

I am using .Net Frameworks WSDL utility to generate client stub. The problem is that, this utility is not generating some classes and some function in some other classes.

The command that I firing from MS-visual studio command prompt is as follows,

```
wsdl /l:CS /protocol:SOAP ../XXXService.wsdl ../XXXSchema.xsd
```

This generating the faulty client stub.
XSD elements for which I am getting the wrong code generated are as follows,

```
<xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdTime" type=`enter code here`"xs:dateTime"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="emailAddress" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="isBounce" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fromName" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="isFrom" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="isReply" type="xs:boolean"/>
          </xs:choice>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="organizationId" type="tns:OrganizationId"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ownerId" type="tns:UserId"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Code generated is,

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fromName", typeof(string))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("isBounce", typeof(bool))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("isFrom", typeof(bool))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("isReply", typeof(bool))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
```

Whereas If I use the WSDLToJava tool in the same way I get proper setter and getter methods in the code.